# Do the blocks in DEFLATE always start from byte boundary?

Tags: deflate

In DEFLATE specification (RFC 1951), it does explain about how the blocks are structured, but because of my shortage in English, I can't find how the blocks are relayed.

When uncompressed block(BTYPE 00 in RFC 1951) first shows up, and if it's not the final block, it's obvious that the next block will show up at the byte boundary, as the structure of uncompressed block should always end up at the byte boundary.

However, in case of other blocks (compressed block), we can't say that End of the Block symbol (255) end up at the byte boundary. In this case, should we fill up zeroes till byte boundary or can we just relay the next block right after the End of the Block symbol regardless of the byte boundary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The next block starts at the next bit, regardless of the byte boundary.